# Appsync Cognito User Pools login with OIDC provider

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

I've created an AppSync GraphQL API with Amazon Cognito User Pool as the default authorization mode. I have set up Amazon Cognito user pools as well and I can confirm I can create new users who can login. I can also login with the credentials from my OIDC provider (keycloak).

The problem is querying from Appsync Queries console. I am able to 'login with user pool' using users that I have created. However I am unable to login with user pools using the credentials from the OIDC provider.

Is there something I am missing? Really appreciate it!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Are you federating your OIDC provider through User Pools? The AppSync login screen doesn't support federated users but only regular User Pools users.

However, AppSync supports OIDC providers directly and you should be able to test by using the JWT token that you obtain when you login with your OIDC provider.

Comment: When you say 'federating your OIDC provider through user pools'... do you mean add all of my users from my OIDC provider to the user pool? Is there a way to actually do that because I was only able to login through Cognito User Pool as a user from my OIDC provider.